# Weekly callendar view in react-day-picker

Tags: reactjs, calendar, react-day-picker

I am using react-day-picker in a project and I need a week view in calendar widget so that i could display booked events per week, has anyone tried to implement this feature and is it possible with this lib? There is https://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPicker/#renderWeek but im not sure if I would be able to fill it with the data. Or which other library would you recommend?

thanks